# c# Generic list filter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of objects. My classes looks like this:

```
    class Line
    {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public object B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    }

class More_B
{
    public Information Information { get { return _Information; }}
    public Description Description { get { return _Description ; }}

    private Information  _Information  = new Information();
    private Description  _Description  = new Description ();
}

class Information
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Type { get; set;}
    public string Further_Info { get; set;}
}
```

In my main class at the end I get all data inside `Line` class like this.

```
More_B info = new More_B();

 Line main = new Line();
 main.A = "Information about device";
 main.B = info;
 main.C = "Some more information could be display here";
 list3.Add(main);
```

So at the end I get list inside which I have all 3 fields `A` `B` `C`. I have my string values in `A` and `C` and in `B` when I check in debug mode I have Information object and inside of it I have all fields like `Name` `Type` and `Further_Info`.

I later want to filter this column based on these values "Name" "Type" and "Further_Info", I tried it this way but it is not working. (I binded my list to DataView to be able to use RowFilter).

```
view2.RowFilter = "Line like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'";
```

How can I do it right?

I am new to C#, so please forgive me, if I did something wrong. If something is hard to understand, let me know and I will try to post more of my code explaining what I did.

EDIT: When I use this statement `view2.RowFilter = "Line like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'";` I get error `Cannot perform 'Like' operation on read_display.More_B and System.String.`

EDIT2: I have 2 more methods for creating datatable for my class and then I do it like this: `DataTable ListAsDataTable2 = BuildDataTable2<Line>(list3); DataView ListAsDataView2 = ListAsDataTable2.DefaultView; this.dataGridView4.DataSource = view2 = ListAsDataView2;`

Comment: view2 is object of my DataView. I did it this way to be able to use RowFilter. It was not working without binding this data to DataView.

Comment: Post code which you used for Binding

Comment: But maybe it can be done in different way, without using DataView?

Comment: As a sidenote, you should use `textBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''")` to escape the quotes from the `textBox2`.

Comment: Edit your question to fit this code as comments are not for code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
public class Line
{
   public string A {get;set;}
   public More_B B {get;set;}
   public string C {get;set;}         

}

public class Information
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public string Type { get; set;}
   public string Further_Info { get; set;}
}

public class More_B:Information
{
   public string CusotmField {get;set;}
}

var B_Object = new More_B (Name = "The B", Type = "Some type", Further_Info = "More Info");
IList<More_B> B_List=new List<More_B>();
var searchObj = B_List.Where(x => x.Name=="The B").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I will check if this will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is error in RowFilter. Since Line is not a column, it shouldn't be used in Filter. Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
view2.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%' OR Type like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%' OR Further_Info like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%' "
```